# function being called for entire row in python matrix of objects instead of single object

Tags: python-3.x

```
class temp:
 def __init__(self):
  self.a = 1
 def toggle(self):
  self.a ^= 1
 def __repr__(self):
  return str(self.a)
```

I have a class defined as above.
I make a matrix using this class as

```
>>> matrix = [[temp()]*5 for x in range(5)]
```

when i do,

```
>>> matrix #gives
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> matrix[0][1].toggle()
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

It should has just toggled the **[0][1]** entry, instead of entire **0** row.
Am I missing something here ?? 
I am using python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind, you are using the `*` operator with objects.

This doesn't work like you think it does 
(You get 5 references to the same object):

```
lst = [Object()]*5
```

If you change one, the rest are automatically changed since they refer to the same address in memory.

Instead, try:

```
class temp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def toggle(self):
        self.a ^= 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.a)

matrix = [[temp() for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
print(matrix)
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

matrix[0][0].toggle()
print(matrix)
# [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav